# How can I make the screen layout the same for 2 Android phones, using Xamarin C#?

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout, xamarin.android

I wrote a Wordle app (haven't we all?) for Xamarin Android C#. I used Absolute Layout, as sample code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:text="Start new game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="10px"
        android:layout_y="5px"
        android:minWidth="150px"
        android:minHeight="80px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/startNewGameButton_id"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
    <Button
        android:text="Show word"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="280px"
        android:layout_y="5px"
        android:minWidth="5px"
        android:minHeight="80px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/showWordButton_id"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11_id"
        android:layout_width="80px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
        android:layout_x="20px"
        android:layout_y="100px"
        android:height="50px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="30px"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#9999cc"
        android:singleLine="false"/> 
    <TextView
```

Here's a pic of the two phones side by side:
[image: Photo of two phones running the same app]

How can I make the phone on the left show the app using all the screen, like the phone on the right? If I make it correct for that one, the app on the other phone is too big and spills off the side and bottom, half of the TextViews no longer visible because they are off screen to the right and down.

Comment: While I'm not too familiar with the Android native, the way to resolve this is to move away from hardcoded sizes. It looks like that Android has a GridLayout that may be better suited for what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this.

**One row using LinearLayout with weights:**

```xml
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/row1"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="A"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="B"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="C"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="D"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="E"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: LinearLayout]

What matters here is that you set the orientation of the LinearLayout to tell which direction it should flow. Then add the weights on each TextView. I've set it to 0.2 to accommodate 5 items.

One thing to consider about LinearLayout with weights is that it can be expensive to use in terms of time it takes laying out. It also makes for a nested layout, which also can have severe performance implications in some cases.

Another, more efficient approach.

**ConstraintLayout and chains:**

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:text="A"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    tools:text="B"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    tools:text="C"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    tools:text="D"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:text="E"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Chaining means that each element references the previous and next in the chain to position itself relative to it.

The advantage of ConstraintLayout is the guarantees it provides of performance, but also the flexibility you get to make Widgets size themselves according to percentages. The layout also is super flat as you don't need an additional `LinearLayout` for each row. So two rows would be:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
    tools:text="A"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    tools:text="B"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView4"
    tools:text="C"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView5"
    tools:text="D"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:text="E"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView7"
    tools:text="F"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
    tools:text="G"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView9"
    tools:text="H"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView10"
    tools:text="I"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:text="J"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Flat, non-overdrawing layout. And the result looks like:

[image: ConstraintLayout 2 rows]

Things to make sure you do when using ConstraintLayout. Every child needs an id. ConstraintLayout should in most cases be the root layout. There is usually no need to nest anything in a ConstraintLayout. If you are doing so, you are probably using it wrong.

A good idea is to familiarize yourself with the [documentation of ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout). There are some very powerful features in this layout.

Another thing I noticed with your layout. You are using `px` values, which is usually not good. It doesn't scale with the DPI of the screen.

Instead for Widgets use `dp` and for text sizes use `sp`.